# Sort the Array and move all the repeated Elements to End

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have encountered this question in my recent interview.

An array is given, I need to sort the array and all the duplicate elements should be at the end.

Example:
input: {7,4,2,3,3,5,3,11,9,2}

Since 2 & 3 are repeated elements they should occur at the end of Array.

Output: {4,5,7,9,11,2,2,3,3,3}

I am free to use any other data structure. No constraints.

Comment: Do you need a simple solution or a super effecient one? If you need effeciency please also provide input constraints (how many numbers and how big).

Comment: @Blaž Zupančič. No constraints. I gave solution with help of sorting and hashing. But he didn't satisfied. He needs a solution with sorting and minimal operations.

Comment: Are you sure te output isn't supposed to be {2,3,4,5,7,9,11,2,3,3} ?

Comment: @m69. No. If element is repeated, all of it occurrences should be at last.

Comment: So you don't need to *sort*, but rather you need to arrange things so that singe items appear first in the list, followed by repeated items. Could your output be `{7,4,5,11,9,3,3,2,2}`? That is, does the order of the items matter, so long as the single are to the left and the repeated are to the right?

Comment: No. Array needs to be sorted. Order of items matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE_ARRAY repeated, unique
SORT inputArray
ADD MINIMAL_POSSIBLE_VALUE TO inputArray
TRAVERSE inputArray i=index (from 2nd element to last):
   IF inputArray[i-1] == inputArray[i]:
      2X: ADD inputArray[i] TO repeated
      i++
      WHILE i < LENGTH(inputArray) - 1 and inputArray[i-1] == inputArray[i]:
         ADD inputArray[i] TO repeated
         i++
   ELSE:   
      ADD inputArray[i-1] TO unique
PRINT MERGED(unique, repeated)
```

You will be sorting your array so duplicate values form patches. You will then distribute the array to unique values array and repeated values array and print them both.

The third line `ADD MINIMAL_POSSIBLE_VALUE TO inputArray` just adds a dummy element to the array that will never get printed but saves you some IF statements.

```js
// algorithm
function algorithm(input) {
  input.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
  input.push(Number.MIN_VAL);
  var repeated = [], unique = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i - 1] == input[i]) {
      repeated.push(input[i], input[i]);
      i++;
      while (i < input.length - 1 && input[i - 1] == input[i]) {
        repeated.push(input[i]);
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      unique.push(input[i - 1]);
    }
  }
  return unique.concat(repeated);
}

// driver
inputBox = document.getElementById('input-box');
outputBox = document.getElementById("output-box");
inputBox.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  outputBox.innerHTML = algorithm(inputBox.value.split(/[\s,]+/).map(Number));
});
```

```html
<input id="input-box">
<div id="output-box"></div>
```

Comment: I think this will work. I'm curious whether we can solve this in place?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with C# using the sort method of List

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 7, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 11, 9, 2, 5 };

        List<int> tmp = new List<int> { };
        List<int> rep = new List<int> {};

        //sorting the list
        list.Sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++) 
        {
            int cantidad = list.LastIndexOf(list[i]) - list.IndexOf(list[i]);
            if ( cantidad != 0)
            {
                //found repetitions
                rep.AddRange(list.GetRange(list.IndexOf(list[i]), cantidad + 1));
                i += cantidad;
            }
            else tmp.Add(list[i]);
        }
        tmp.AddRange(rep);

        foreach (int data in tmp)
            Console.WriteLine(data);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Solution with C# sorting out manually

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 7, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 11, 9, 2 };

        List<int> tmp = new List<int> {};
        List<int> rep = new List<int> {};

        foreach (int data in list)
        {
            if (tmp.Count() > 0)
            {
                int posicion = -1;
                bool bandera = false;
                for (var i=0; i < tmp.Count(); i++)
                {
                    //searching a repetition
                    if (tmp[i] == data)
                    {
                        tmp.RemoveAt(i);
                        //adding to the repeated list at the end or in a determined position
                        for (var j = 0; j < rep.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            if (rep[j] > data)
                            {
                                bandera = true;
                                rep.Insert(j, data); //the one that was deleted
                                rep.Insert(j, data); //the one at the original list
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!bandera)
                        {
                            bandera = true;
                            rep.Add(data); //the one that was deleted
                            rep.Add(data); //the one at the original list
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    //saving the position to be inserted
                    if (tmp[i] > data)
                    {
                        posicion = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //was not a repetition
                if (!bandera)
                {
                    bool banderaRep = false;
                    //searching in the repeated list
                    for (var i = 0; i < rep.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (rep[i] == data)
                        {
                            banderaRep = true;
                            rep.Insert(i, data);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //was not in the repeated list
                    if (!banderaRep)
                    {
                        if (posicion == -1)
                            tmp.Add(data);
                        else
                            tmp.Insert(posicion, data);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                tmp.Add(data);
        }
        //join
        tmp.AddRange(rep);

        foreach (int data in tmp)
            Console.WriteLine(data);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: What is "the sort class?"

Comment: sorry, not class, method, already corrected. The second solution propose the sorting process manually, without using the benefits of language

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a map data structure, not a very efficient solution but it works nonetheless:

1> Traverse through the vector counting frequency of numbers in a map
2> Iterate over the map (elements will be in sorted order) pushing unique elements in a vector and repeated elements in another vector
3> Push repeated elements in the sorted array

Code in C++

```cpp
vector<int> sortUnique(const vector<int> & nums) {

// Step 1
map<int, int> numFreq;
for (auto it : nums) {
    if (numFreq.count(it) == 0) {
        numFreq[it] = 1;
    }
    else {
        numFreq[it]++;
    }
}

// Step 2
vector<int> sorted;
sorted.reserve(nums.size());
vector<int> repeated;
repeated.reserve(nums.size());
for (auto it : numFreq) {
    if (it.second == 1) {
        sorted.push_back(it.first);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < it.second; i++) {
            repeated.push_back(it.first);
        }
    }
}
// Push repeated elements at the end
for (auto it : repeated) {
    sorted.push_back(it);
}
return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a dictionary of values with associated counts. You didn't specify a language, so I'll give you some pseudo code.

**Note** This does not result in sorted output.

First, scan the array and create your dictionary of values and counts:

```
dict = create new dictionary
for each item in array
    if dict contains item
        increase count for that item in the dictionary
    else
        add item to dictionary with count of 1
```

Now create two indexes: one starting at 0, and other at (array.length - 1). For each item in the dictionary, if it is a single, write it at the front of the array. Otherwise write `count` items at the back of the array. Like this:

```
frontIndex = 0
backIndex = array.Length - 1
for each item in dictionary
    if item.count == 1
        array[frontIndex] = item
        frontIndex = frontIndex + 1
    else
       for i = 0 to item.Count-1
           array[backIndex-i] = item
       backIndex = backIndex - item.Count
```

Time is O(n) to build the dictionary, and O(n) to repopulate the array. Extra space is O(n).

Comment: dictionary does not guarantee that items will be in sorted order so in your second part in the for each loop items will not come out in sorted order. I used a BST in my solution which makes sure items will be sorted.

Comment: @RandomGuy: The OP's example doesn't show the items sorted, so I didn't sort them.

Comment: What I mean to say is while writing items to the front of the array you are assuming that items retrieved in a sorted order, which is not true.

Comment: @RandomGuy: No, I'm not assuming that the items are in sorted order. I don't care if the output is sorted, because the OP's example output isn't sorted.

Comment: @RandomGuy: So I was wrong: OP does want the output sorted. I'll have to think on the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Swift 3 (beta 3) to describe an high level implementation for your problem.

```
let list = [7,4,2,3,3,5,3,11,9,2]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: list)
let singles = list.filter { countedSet.count(for: $0) == 1 }
let duplicates = list.filter { countedSet.count(for: $0) > 1 }
let res = singles.sorted() + duplicates.sorted()
```

### Line #2

This class creates an index, it associate to each value it number of occurrencies.

### Lines #3 and #4

Here I am filtering the original array. I am putting into `singles` the values with only 1 occurrences and into `duplicates` the values that appear more then once.

### Line #5

Finally I sort `singles` and `duplicates` and I concatenate them